# Java MultiThreading behaviour explanation

Tags: java, multithreading, indexoutofboundsexception

I am learning Java multithreading. I wrote a small piece of code and results in some output which i am not able to understand..please help with some explanation.
Posting the code below.

```
package com.java.learn;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListTestWithMultiThread {
    static final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                    list.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
                }
                System.out.println("List size at thread 0 : " + list.size());
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 101; i <= 200; i++) {
                    list.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
                }
                System.out.println("List size at thread 1 : " + list.size());
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Some of the o/p in various runs:
    List size at thread 0 : 134
    List size at thread 1 : 200

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" List size at thread 0 : 101
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 17
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.java.learn.ListTestWithMultiThread$2.run(ListTestWithMultiThread.java:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    List size at thread 0 : 106
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 58
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.java.learn.ListTestWithMultiThread$2.run(ListTestWithMultiThread.java:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing an data-structure (the `list`) that is not designed for concurrent access in parallel without protecting it (e.g. via `synchronized`). This will eventually corrupt the internals of the data-structure leading to weird behavior like the exception you get.

Here are two ways how to procted it:

1. Use a concurrent data-structure:

`List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());`

2. Use `synchronized` to protect the list:

   ```
   synchronized(list) {
         list.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
   }
   ```

**Edit**: Since you asked for it, here is how the `ArrayList` can get corrupted.
An `ArrayList` is backed by an array that has to be resized when the list grows. Resizing here means an new, larger array is allocated and the content of the old one copied to the new one. Here are parts of [the code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l199) that does that:

```
int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
...
elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
```

Now imagine the following: Thread A start resizing the array, it computes the new capacity and starts copying the data in line 4. But before it can copy the reference of the new array to `elementData` it gets stoped for whatever reason (this happens all the time). Now Thread B starts resizing the array and finishes. Then it inserts more values into the list and resizes the array again and finishes. Thread B now assumes that the list is large enough for a new value, but before it inserts the value, thread A wakes up and overrides `elementData` with the reference to the smaller array it has created. Thread B now tries to insert a value into the smaller array and gets an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This all is kinda unlikely but it can happen as you see.

Comment: If i need to use syncronized(list){}, then i need to make it in both   threads or in any one.

Comment: In both threads - basically wherever you modify it in a concurrent way

Comment: Does making reference variable list static or not has nay impact on tht behavior that we got.

Comment: No that does not make any difference

Comment: Martin, as there is a single shared list object, how can two threads create different arrays internally. Are they not using the same array created internally.

Comment: They both start with the same array in the list, but at some point both call `new int[...]` which will give each thread a different array and then it depends on the timing of who overwrites `elementData` first.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the `list` variable from two different threads without any synchronization (locking). This will result undefined behavior.

You might want to try replacing the list declaration with the following:

```
static final List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

Another option is to use `Vector` instead of `ArrayList`. `Vector` is a synchronized collection implementing the `List` interface.

Comment: I tried running the code several times the ouptut is : List size at thread 0 : 100
List size at thread 1 : 200  all the time..

Comment: Even if I make list as static volatile which should write directly to main memory and make gurantee of vissibilty to other threads,then also same behavior

Comment: Vaibhav, I also got that o/p some times but not all times. some times results in exception as shown in my o/p shared

Comment: @KamalBindra `volatile` has little to do with synchronizing data between threads

Comment: @KamalBindra, `volatile` would have helped had this been a simple variable (say, an `int`) that is accessed from both threads. However, since you are invoking methods on the list object which is more complicated (and internally manages multiple data structures), this is not enough.

Comment: @MartinS according to what I understood after reading about volatile that it also helps in protecting shared objects. Please share your thoughts if I missed something

Comment: @KamalBindra `volatile` prevents some caching and optimizations which makes it safer to access a variable - the problem is that it does not protect the internals of whatever the variable are.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: @KamalBindra, read [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp06197/):  "Volatile variables share the visibility features of synchronized, but none of the atomicity features. This means that threads will automatically see the most up-to-date value for volatile variables. They can be used to provide thread safety, but only in a very restricted set of cases: those that do not impose constraints between multiple variables or between a variable's current value and its future values"

Answer (score 0):

- `ArrayList` is not thread safe. `ArrayList` implementation is backed up
  by an Array. There is size variable associated `ArrayList`. Whenever we
  add any element to `ArrayList` it first ensures it capacity and then
  adds elements to the array. What state of array list is visible to
  each Thread is undefined as you are sharing non thread safe
  implementation between two threads.
- If you start any thread first, do not assume that it will finish its 
  task first. There is no predicted behavior.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. Can anyone help me with some pictorial representation of list in memory that made it corrupt and resulted in arrayindexoutofbound  exception. It would rally help me to understand more.

Comment: @KamalBindra I added an explanation how this can happen to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think error is outofbound and not java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
To understand the output you should first understand working of arraylist internally. when you add arraylist what happens exactly internally.
How the size of ArrayList grows dynamically?

Inside the add(Object) , you will find the following code

```
 public boolean add(E e)

{

     ensureCapacity(size+1);
     elementData[size++] = e;         
     return true;
}
```

Important point to note from above code is that we are checking the capacity of the ArrayList , before adding the element. ensureCapacity()  determines what is the current size of occupied elements and what is the maximum size of the array. If size of the  filled elements (including the new element to be added to the ArrayList class) is greater than the  maximum size of the array then increase the size of array. But the size of the array can not be increased dynamically. So what happens internally is new Array is created with capacity.

So here in your case your 
Thread 1 and Thread 2 tried and succeed to add elements simultaneously without synchronization error fortunately. Until the Arraylist is full now both threads create 2 different new array. One of thread wins to change reference to its newly created array suppose its thread 1. Now thread 2 tries to copy all elements of newly referenced array unfortunately he is unaware about size change of array thus recalculate size of array and try to add new element at top of the array which does not exist.Thus throws exception out of bound.

Please correct me if I'm understanding wrong.

Comment: How two threads create two different arrays if arraylist list created is a single shared object in memory and also reference is also static.

Comment: Basically arraylist is simple array behind scene thus arraylist size is increased dynamically by creating new array object and changing its reference to that new array.So as both thread see that arraylist is full then both create new array.

Comment: Firstly reference variable list to arraylist is staic and final both that means ref cant be changed. Secondly agreed upon that arraylist is array internally and when size increases new array created but that new one will be single for both threads or different for both threads. if two different for both threads, how can ref be changed.

Comment: I understood your question final means you cannot assign a object to that object means its reference cannot be changed. But that doesn't mean final keyword is applicable to internal arrays. Internally it can be modified as it wants.Because we are not changing reference of the class object[ArrayList] as a whole but the internal array object.